# Printing multiple files

Tags: java, printing

I am working on a JSP/Servlet application where we have document management type product and we want to batch print i.e. multiple files(pdf, images, words etc.) at a time(without opening print dialog box).

I had searched a lot about this and I found that applets might help but it requires certification installation.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add some mor detail? thanks

Comment: @Coffee what you want to know more?